# Unreal Engine 4.25, stdlib C++ 17/20 and Visual Studio Code status between them and/or integration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

I have seen there are several ways to add C++17.
I know that earlier ,like in 2015.  we couldn't use, or we had to wrap containers from std. I am interested, is now better situation with using C++ stdlib in UE4? Is standard C++  now more (or totally) integrated with UE4 version of C++, or can be that done with some VSC(or UE4) add-on?

Comment: This page covers the codingstandards Epic currently is using themselves https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/#useofstandardlibraries they name some exceptions/unavoidables but still conclude with "Standard containers and strings should be avoided except in interop code."

Comment: So status quo... Thank you very much Jabokoe

Comment: You can totally use the standard containers if you want but they have no support for unreal's reflection (which includes loss of garbage collection, serialization, network replication, blueprint and python compatibility). You'll have to convert your containers when talking to the engine, and you'll lose the custom allocators for each container(though admittedly they can be replicated for std types if you want to). I would say you need to have a tangible problem that the std lib has the most effective solution for, all I can think of is interop/compatibility with 3rd party libs as above.

Comment: That is what I meant with this question. Because I had seen like "c++17 support", and after that I had seen "not recommended" on other page, so I was like: what is truth. So, yeah, I understand - "very useful integration"